# .htaccess Redirect with Cloudflare location

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, geolocation, cloudflare

I'm really struggling to place redirects into my .htaccess file based on the cloud flare country code. I'm either getting "too many redirect errors" or 500 internal errors using examples from across this site.

I currently have this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)$" Country=$1

RewriteCond %{ENV:Country} GB
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

So I need the default domain to be http://example.com

but if a country code of GB comes from cloudflare for example, I need it to redirect to:

http://example.com/gb

With my limited knowledge of .htaccess is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^GB$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^gb/ /gb%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]
```

Redirect `http://example.com/test` to `http://example.com/gb/test` when the request comes from a user with `CF-IPCountry=GB` which is not already using a link with `/gb/`

Comment: Hi, this actually works as expected, however, it breaks all of my resources (images / css files etc.) as i think it is also redirecting the requests for those. is there a way to avoid this without having a copy of everything in sub folder?

Comment: I add one rule to avoid rewrite for images or css files.

Comment: That code worked, but... what if i want to add more countries to redirect to same url? is that possible (for example mexico and spain redirect to mydomain.com/es/ And one last question, is it posible so it just redirects if it is home page? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use `!^(gb|mx|sp)/ /gb%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R,L]`

Comment: For home page `RewriteRule ^$  /gb/ [R,L]`